# Mathematica 9: installation of "Extras" fails

Tags: windows, installation

I installed Mathematica 9 on my Windows 7 system (installed the font patch afterwards so the BSOD are gone) but the "Extras" package installation fails claiming it can't de-install the Mathematica 8 packages.

I de-installed Mathematica 8 and tried re-installing Mathematica 9 again but it keeps claiming the Mathematica 8 add-ons can't be removed. At the end CDF (amongst other stuff?) is not working in the browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Nasser, No I mean the add-on during the standard install. I also believe that they're labeled extra packages but I'm not sure. It's the part where CDF browser plugins get installed.

Comment: For Mac: when opened, the Mathematica 9 `.dmg` image includes the installer includes a separate item "extra packages"

Comment: (I didn't edit soon enough my preceding comment to complete it. Here it is:) For Mac: when opened, the Mathematica 9 `.dmg` image includes, alongside `Mathematica.app` itself, an `Extras.pkg" for installing the browser plug-in and indexing add-on.

For Windows, and this was for Mathematica 8, after you ran the installer for Mathematica itself, you were then prompted whether to install the extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by de-installing Mathematica 9. Then I re-installed Mathematica 8 which gave an error message about the deinstall msg fle not being present. However the installation continued. Then I de-installed the extra package through the control panel (with windows) first and then de-installed Mathematica 8. After that I removed all directories described at http://support.wolfram.com/kb/4730
Then I reinstalled Mathematica 9 (with the latest package).
No more errors!
However the CDF browser plugin is only installed for Chrome. No idea why because IE is my default browser. I suppose I can install the plug-in for IE from the Wolfram site but I'm doubting if it's not better to wait a bit.